# sql how to write this as a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sql query

```
Select * from Name
where surname in ('test1', 'test2')
```

which works

But I wanted to do the following

```
DECLARE @Surname as VARCHAR(100)
set @Surname = 'test1' + ',' + 'test2'

Select * from Name
where surname in @Surname
```

this is the actual query used

```
DECLARE @COESNo as VARCHAR(100)
set @COESNo = '121108883' + ',' + '121108890'

declare @sql varchar(max) 
set @sql = 'select [LEI_ACCEPT] , [PREFERED_LEI] , [INSPECTION_COMPANY], [INSP_ACCEPT] from [CERTIFICATE_DETAILS] where [Certificate_no] in (' 
set @sql = @sql + @COESNo + ')'

exec  @sql
```

get the error

```
The name 'select [LEI_ACCEPT] , [PREFERED_LEI] , [INSPECTION_COMPANY], [INSP_ACCEPT] from [CERTIFICATE_DETAILS] where [Certificate_no] in (121108883,121108890)' is not a valid identifier.
```

doesn't seem to work

any ideas

Comment: you will need to create your statement and execute - like `declare @sql varchar(max)` `set @sql = 'Select * from Name
where surname in ('` `set @sql = @sql + @surname + ')'` After creating the statement just say `exec @sql`

Comment: You should pray and hope noone has weird names or deliberately tries to make sql injection into your system with the suggested approac. (http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Why do you  want to do this? I think you we have the xy problem here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Your problem as stated makes no sense. We need to know where you get your IN list from and how will you be populating them in your script. Manually? Excel? an application? a stored procedure?

Comment: i am just writing a script for maintannece for the helpdesk staff, there is no worry about sql injection etc.  The values are populated by hand by staff.. this is something they might have to do once in a while

Answer (score 2):

There are two popular solutions.

First one is to build string with query and use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to run it.

Second one is to write (or find) function (something like `SplitText2Table()`) which converts comma separated string to table and write query which use this function -- something like:

```
select * 
from name
where surname in (select item from SplitText2Table(@surnames))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for the exact problem in the question. But maybe (?) you could instead use this workaround:

```
declare @SurName1 nvarchar(20)
declare @SurName2 nvarchar(20)

set @SurName1='test1'
set @SurName2='test2'

select * from [Name] where [surname] in (@SurName1, @SurName2)
```

Answer (score -1):

you will need to create your statement and execute - like

```
declare @sql varchar(max) 
set @sql = 'Select * from [Name] where surname in (' 
set @sql = @sql + @surname + ')'
```

After creating the statement just say

```
exec @sql
```

You can also check the formed query is correct or not using `print`

```
print @sql
```

Please use print before execution of the command (this will help you in correcting the query is there is any error.).

**EDIT**: 
As per the comment - Since Name is a keyword for SQL - we will need to use square bracket against it. I have modified the statement in my answer.

**Edit 2**: Based on further comments - 
Firstly I would like to know the datatype of `Certificate_no` column in your database. 
If it is a `varchar` field you will need to have single quotes around each value.

The name `SELECT [LEI_ACCEPT] , [PREFERED_LEI] , [INSPECTION_COMPANY], [INSP_ACCEPT] FROM[CERTIFICATE_DETAILS] WHERE [Certificate_no] IN ('121108883','121108890')`

You will need to create -

```
DECLARE  @COESNo as VARCHAR(100)
set  @COESNo = '''121108883''' + ',' + '''121108890'''
```

Since Certificate number is varchar the string build will need a single quote in formed query which will appear with three single quotes.

I have created Working DEMO for you on SQL FIDDLE - [CLICK HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/772fd/7)

Comment: when I print it, I get the correct sql, but when i use exec it says the name is not a valid identifier

Comment: Do you have a table named as Name - if yes then use square brackets against `[Name]`

Comment: @user2206329 - try to work out with appropriate string concatenation standards you should get the query.

Comment: Did you gone through the SQL Fiddle - didn't that helped you to create your sql statement.

Comment: not really, when I do a select to see the query, it is fine, but when I use exec it errors out